# Can somebody recommend a good U3D library?

Tags: c++, pdf, 3d, u3d

I need to put some 3D images into PDF files, and PDF uses Universal 3D (U3D) formats.  I don't like the U3D Sourceforge project (basically what Intel released after the ECMA standardization effort).

Does anybody know of good U3D libraries I could use?  I'm using C++ on Microsoft Windows, FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VCGLib](http://vcg.sourceforge.net/index.php/Main_Page) is a mesh processing library that has a U3D exporter and a variety of importers (see http://vcg.sourceforge.net/index.php/Tutorial#File_Formats). [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) is a tool built on top of it.

Comment: Thanks - I'd run into MeshLab, but hadn't found VCGLib.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer would be [Visual Technology Services](http://www.pdf3d.co.uk/) with [PDF3D](http://www.pdf3d.co.uk/pdf/PDF3D-SDK-ProductBrief.pdf) (PDF link).  I've started evaluating it and I like what I see so far.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your position of not liking the U3D sourceforge project. People at my company is having problems with it when exporting large models: it runs out of memory.

The project has explicitly stated that it has memory issues on its TODO list and is dead since 2007, so I strongly recommend you to go elsewhere.

Comment: There is no elsewhere, as far as I can tell.  There's the sourceforge project, and people who put wrappers on the sourceforge project.  Moreover, I need U3D to embed three-dimensional images into PDFs.  The situation isn't ideal, but I really don't know of an alternative way to put 3D into PDFs without using that software.

Comment: I even posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676303/exporting-u3d-pdf3d-from-visual-c